# Translations of some of Ladyzhenskaya's papers?

Tags: translation

I am looking for English (or Spanish...?) translations of the following papers by Olga Ladyzhenskaya:

- "On the solution of a mixed problem for
  hyperbolic equations", Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat., 15:6 (1951), 545–562 [Link to paper in Russian](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=3333&option_lang=eng)
- "The method of finite differences in the
  theory of partial differential equations",  Uspekhi Mat. Nauk, 12:5(77) (1957), 123–148 [Link to paper in Russian](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=7707&option_lang=eng)

I have tried to use MathSciNet to get access to these online, to no avail. Any help would be strongly appreciated.

Comment: Spanish? Anyway, it would be helpful if you offer more details than titles when asking others to look for them. For example, you call these papers, but I am wondering if the first item might be a book: http://www.twirpx.com/file/1909279/. (The title of this 280 page book, from 1953, is not exactly the title you wrote but it is close.) The second item is a 25+ page paper at http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=7707&option_lang=rus from 1957; click the hyperlinked text "PDF файл" to get the .pdf, but of course it will be in Russian, which is not what you want.

Comment: these are links to the Russian originals of the two papers: [On the solution of a mixed problem for hyperbolic equations](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=3333&option_lang=eng) and [The method of finite differences in the theory of partial differential equations](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=7707&option_lang=eng) --- both are freely accessible online, but have not been translated.

Comment: It will help if you give Russian references. Or at least the year.

Comment: Thank you for your comments; I will expand on details on the Russian editions. If for whatever reason there exists a Spanish translation before an English translation, that would serve my purposes too; of course this is quite unlikely.

Comment: The second paper is translated in [Ladyženskaja, O. A., The method of finite differences in the theory of partial differential equations. Amer. Math. Soc. Transl. (2) 20 1962 77–104]. I pulled this from mathscinet. Any good US library should have it. For the first paper it is probably most efficient to find a Russian speaking colleague. Also I hear there are scanning programs that would extract the text from a pdf, which you can then feed to google translate; with some patience the procedure is quite efficient.

Comment: Igor, thanks for your comment. I have been able to get hold of the second paper's translation. The first paper is probably not translated, I guess.